# Inserting wrong values/overwriting values due for loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, laravel

Hi gladly I want to save a project and a task at the same time in the database. But that did not go well for me. Let me illustrate it for you what actually is happening:

**Screenshot adding a project and a task before saving it:**

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l9Iv.png

**Screenshot after saving a project and a task:**

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztHHo.png

As you can see the problem is, that it is overwriting values.

Here is a screenshot of how my array looks like:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfF6S.png

And here is the code that I use to insert a project and a task to an order:

Orderproject.php:

```
static public function storeOrderProjects($inputArr )
{   

//die('xx inputArr val: ' .print_r($inputArr));

        for($i=0;$i< count( $inputArr['id_project']);$i++ ){

            $data = array(
                        'id_order' => $inputArr['id'],
                        'id_project' => $inputArr['id_project'][$i],
                        'hour' => $inputArr['hour'][$i],
                        'hourprice' => $inputArr['hour_salary'][$i],
                        'totalprice' => $inputArr['total_salary'][$i],
                        'createdBy' => Auth::user()->id
                    ); 

            Orderproject::create($data);

        }

}
```

Ordertask.php:

```
static public function storeOrderTasks($inputArr )
{   

//die('xx inputArr val: ' .print_r($inputArr));

        for($i=0;$i< count( $inputArr['id_task']);$i++ ){

            $data = array(
                        'id_order' => $inputArr['id'],
                        'id_task' => $inputArr['id_task'][$i],
                        'hour' => $inputArr['hour'][$i],
                        'hourprice' => $inputArr['hour_salary'][$i],
                        'totalprice' => $inputArr['total_salary'][$i],
                        'createdBy' => Auth::user()->id
                    ); 

            Ordertask::create($data);

        }
}
```

I know what the problem is, in the for loop the id_project is on the same index with the values "5, 5" of the element hour and hour_salary. I think I'm really close, but still don't know how to fix this. Can someone maybe help me, please? Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: You probably ought to embed your screenshots in your question - that's the preferred way around here, to ward off link-rot. Do you not use and IDE with a debugger? Breakpoint, examine your variables, et voila!

Answer (score 1):

You have just one value in `$inputArr['id_project']`, and so in `$inputArr['id_task']`, therefore both `storeOrderProjects` and `storeOrderTasks` take only the first value, ignoring the second. Using the given structure you should probably loop over `hour`, although, if possible, you should consider using an array structure that better reflects the business logic.

Comment: I have tried "for($i=0;$i< count( $inputArr['hour']);$i++ )" but unfortunately I get the error: "Undefined offset: 1"  Can you or someone else maybe help me, please?

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear what I have tried. You can see it in this link: http://pastebin.com/7gysds1k

Comment: @superkytoz normal about offset undefinef as you then try to access datas from other array that dont exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are counting an array of length 1 so you go through your loop only once with `$i` equal to 0 thus you only insert the first values of the other arrays. The problem is that your hour and hour salary arrays are note the same length that your `id_task` and `id_project` array.